# Plotly plot a vertical line on a time series plot due to conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

Hi I have a dataframe with time series on my x axis and values on my y axis.
I am using Plotly and am trying to plot a vertical line on the x axis where there my df.Alert == 1.
Currently I am using another overlay with red marker to plot it but I wish to switch to a vertical line that is restricted within by the y values of my chart. The values on the y axis should still be determined by my trace plot and not the vertical line.

Is there a way for me to do this?

My code sample is written below

```
Trace = go.Scatter(
    name = "Values",
    x = df.DateTime,
    y = df.Values,
    mode='markers',
    text= "Unit: " + df['Unit'].astype(str),
   ) 

Alert = go.Scatter(
    name = "Alert",
    x = df.DateTime,
    y = df.Values.where(df.Alert == 1),
    mode='markers',
    line = dict(color = "red"),
    text= "Unit: " + df['Unit'].astype(str),
   ) 


layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis = dict(title = "Date and Time"),
    yaxis = dict(title = "Values")
)

data = [Trace, Alert]
figure = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)    
py.iplot(figure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You perfectly describe what you want to do... plot **vline**

- iterate over rows in DF that are *alerts* `fig.add_vline()`

```
n=50
df = pd.DataFrame({"DateTime":pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", freq="15min", periods=n),
                   "Alert":np.random.choice([0]*10+[1], n),
                   "Unit":np.random.choice([0,1,2,3], n),
                   "Values":np.random.uniform(1,10, n)})
                   
Trace = go.Scatter(
    name = "Values",
    x = df.DateTime.astype(str),
    y = df.Values,
    mode='markers',
    text= "Unit: " + df['Unit'].astype(str),
   ) 

layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis = dict(title = "Date and Time"),
    yaxis = dict(title = "Values")
)

data = [Trace]
figure = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)    


for r in df.loc[df.Alert.astype(bool),].iterrows():
    figure.add_vline(x=r[1]["DateTime"],  line_width=1, line_dash="solid", line_color="red")

figure
```

[image]

Comment: how can we add the add_vline using a custom date (for example I need add the vertical lines 2pm ,3 p m  and 6pm )  @rob-raymond